# Doubt on a notation: use of $\wedge$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, notation

The beginning of the page $4$ of [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2770980_Aleksandrov_reflection_and_geometric_evolution_of_hypersurfaces) is defined the following function:

> Let $K > 0$. Define $u_0: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
>
> $u_0(x) = \begin{cases}
>  \text{dist} (x,\Gamma_0) \wedge K \ \text{if} \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \backslash \Omega_0,\\
>  - \text{dist} (x,\Gamma_0) \ \text{if} \ x \in \Omega_0
>  \end{cases}$
>
> which is the signed function to $\Gamma_0$ (cut off by the constant $K$).

Even with this parenthesis, I could not understand what means "$\wedge$". I would like to understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means the min.

Comment: The minimum? If is this, I can't understand yet what this means in the paper. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: "cut off by the constant $K$" means when 'distance' is greater than $K$, return $K$ instead of 'distance'. This is equivalent to taking minimum over 'distance' and $K$.

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, three case can happen. First, $x \in \Omega_0$, and $u_0(x) = -d(x,\Gamma_0)$. Second, $x \notin \Omega_0$ and $d(x,\Gamma_0) \leqslant K$. Then, $u_0(x) = d(x,\Gamma_0)$. Third, $x\notin \Omega_0$ and $d(x,\Gamma_0) > K$. Then, $u_0(x) = K$.